# laravel reactjs put all api request in one get request

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, api, axios

I'm working on a `laravel/reactjs` project and I use Axios to get data from the database with the Laravel API.

I use the Laravel `api.php` and web.php for the API calls.
I have a few pages that do multiple requests at the render of the `reactjs` component but sometimes Laravel throws a random 500 or 403 error when the request are done (1 in 25 or something). Also, calls that go through the web.php have a bit of extra loading time.

So I was wondering if it is a smart idea to make a Laravel function that returns all the data that one page needs at the render. So in react only one get request has to be made at the render.
Is this the best practice or are there any better solutions?

Thanks for helping, If you don't understand the question please tell me.

edit:

the error returned by Laravel :

```
{
    "message": "Server Error"
}{
    "message": "Server Error"
}
```

[image]

Comment: so, to show one page you need to call the api 25 times ?

Comment: Those errors only _seem_ random. Id want to figure out whats causing those and fix that.

Comment: As far as making it one ajax request instead of multiple, that'd depend on what your doing exactly. For example, if doing that made the page take 4 times longer to start loading, its probably a bad idea

Comment: @N69S no only like 5-8 times and some pages with images use the api as well.

Comment: @WesleySmith Laravel does not return an error only "error 500" and I have debug true in .env

Comment: @WesleySmith I use it to get userinfo, categories etc. but the google console log shows that every request is arround 400ms. So I was wondering what the other developers say the best practise is.

Comment: If you follow the REST api convention, then no, each ressource has its web services.

Comment: In my experience, the actual ajax and related processing adds very little overhead and has never been a factor. I would always keep the separate calls for distinctly different things. IHMO, it would be bad practice to merge userinfo and categories into a single API call unless those 2 things were very closely related, and even then, its probably a bad idea.

Comment: @WesleySmith I have added the error, as you can see laravel does not tell that much about the error. If I open the url that had an error trough the google console I dont get  the error.

Comment: @TimeParadox Regarding the errors, look in `storage/logs`, you should see a `laravel.log` file (might have a datetime on the name depending on your config). That file will likely contain logging related to the 500 error (if not check your Apache or Ngnix logs next)

Comment: Regarding the 403 error, `"The 403 Forbidden Error happens when the web page (or other resource) that you're trying to open in your web browser is a resource that you're not allowed to acces"`  Given your use case, Id guess this is rejecting an API token as invalid or unauthorized and start digging there

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest increasing the API throttle in `app/Http/Kernal.php`, you can also use `Route::dispatch` to call routes internally and then group them in a single response:

```
// GET Request
$request = Request::create('/some/url/1', 'GET');
$response = Route::dispatch($request);

// POST Request
$request = Request::create('/some/url/1', 'POST', Request::all());
$response = Route::dispatch($request);
```